# Trying to do an INSERT SELECT to move data from a staging table to another table, but it's a bit complicated

Tags: mysql

I'm doing stuff with a Pokemon database, and I have a staging table:

**pokemontemp(DexNumber(PK), Name, Type, StatTotal, HP, Attack, Defense, SpAttack, SpDefense, Speed)**

and I'm trying to insert the data from that into a table with the same columns except, in the receiving table, the "Type" column is instead the "PokemonTypeId" column, which is a foreign key from the table:

**Types(PokemonTypeId(PK), Type1, Type2)**

which I made to handle the fact that some pokemon are dual type, and the staging table deals with this by having 2 rows for each dual type pokemon, one for each type. Problem is that I can't think of how to write a SELECT statement to grab the 2 types from the 2 rows of a dual type pokemon, match it to a row on the Types table, and insert the PokemonTypeId instead.

I'm using MySQL 8.0

What did I try: I couldn't try anything because I don't know what to try. The only issue I was able to solve was selecting only 1 of the 2 rows for the dual type pokemon and that was with an INSERT IGNORE statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self-join and then join to `Types`, like

```
insert into pokemon(Name, PokemonTypeId, StatTotal, HP, Attack, Defense, SpAttack, SpDefense, Speed)
select first.Name, Types.PokemonTypeId, first.StatTotal, first.HP, first.Attack, first.Defense, first.SpAttack, first.SpDefense, first.Speed
from pokemontemp first
join pokemontemp second
on first.Name = second.Name
join Types
on first.Type = Types.Type1 and second.Type = Types.Type2
```

Things I was not sure about:

- I assumed that the table we are to insert into is called `pokemon`
- I assumed that any Name of Type1 will have exact a single pair with the same name of Type2 and vice versa
- I assumed that the primary key value does not need to be preserved and it's an auto_incremented field

Comment: That didn't quite work, unfortunately. First, the sql command syntax wasn't right, it needs to be "INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...", and are those inner joins or outer joins? I tried to sort of translate what you were intending into what I can use and got this: 
https://imgur.com/a/8QSDOoF (I also posted the daigram of the database table relations I'm working with.)

Comment: @FrankChristian you are right, I have edited my answer. The query is still untested, but it hopefully will work better now

Comment: @FrankChristian if the current answer is still not working for you, then I recommend creating a sqlfiddle with the structure and sample data, so I could test my query until it's working perfectly. The current problem is that I do not have access to something resembling your database to test this query and I don't quite have the time to implement your database based on the EF diagram you have shared. In short: if this is not working yet, a minimal reproducible example will enable me to finalize the query.